# Locally compact space .

Tags: general-topology

How can I show that for every locally compact space $X$ there exists a one-to-one continuous mapping of $X$ onto a compact space. And is it necessary that $X$ is compact since we know that every Hausdorff compact space is locally compact space.
 Thanks for helping me.

Comment: If your definition of compact doesn't include the space being Hausdorff, take the same set and endow it with the indiscrete topology.

Comment: Every compact space is locally compact, not just the ones that are Hausdorff.

Comment: @PandaBear: That depends on which definition of local compactness is used. Some people define $X$ to be locally compact if each point has a local base of compact nbhds, and the one-point compactification of $\Bbb Q$ is not locally compact in this sense.